# Single SXA facet pointing to two different fields from different template

Tags: sxa, search-facet

I have two different page types in the `Sitecore 10.2 SXA` search scope. So **template1** contains `sdate` field and **template2** contains `edate` field for `date`. I need to point the facet to both the fields in order to implement `date range` and `sort by`.

I tried using this field by adding `sdate,edate` in facet but did not work.

[image]

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible just out-of-the-box. What is mostly done in cases like this is to create an extra index field ([ComputedIndexField](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/create-a-computed-index-field.html)) that will contain sdate or edate (depending on the template). This way you can use that field in the facet.